# Using FLTK API, how to find the fullscreen height?

Tags: fltk

`Fl::h()` ***excludes*** the height of the task bar at the bottom.

I have an `Fl_Double_Window` inside an `FL_Window`.  After I make the outer window (`Fl_Window`) full screen using `fullscreen()` method, I want to make the height of the `Fl_Double_Window` equal to the height of the screen.  If I use `innerWindow->size(Fl::w(), Fl::h());` it does not extend its height all the way to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Fl::w()` and `Fl::h()` will give you width and height of the *working area*. After examining [the list of screen functions](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/group__fl__screen.html) I believe your best option is to get the number of screens using the `static int  Fl::screen_count ()` and then use the `static void  Fl::screen_xywh (int &X, int &Y, int &W, int &H, int n)` where n is the index of the screen you want to analyze, typically 0.

If all you care about is the screen below the mouse pointer, use the `static void   Fl::screen_xywh (int &X, int &Y, int &W, int &H)` function.